# Which words define the broad meaning of the following (scientific research-related) sentences?

Tags: science

Background: I'm writing my master's degree dissertation on electrical engineering, related do [electroporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroporation), and I'm trying to define broad meanings for some possible approaches to the electroporation modelling (so I can create subsections with those names): here are the sentences that define them:

Theories of electroporation fall into two broad categories: (I) those based on the pore-formation and breakdown voltage modelling and (II) those that describe the electrical changes after the electroporation aiming to obtain the permeabilization state obtained.

So, the first one tries to model the process with more detail, like molecular dynamics in some cases (would that be phenomenological?). And the second one will model the broader view of the process, not being interested of what actually changed on the structure of the electroporated cells, just what this changes reflects electrically.

I am not sure if you guys can help me out or either if this is the right place to ask that. But thanks in advance anyways.

Note: I'm actually not writing the document in English, I'm not from an English speaking country (as you might notice already), but I'll translate what I get here, if I can.

**EDIT**

The answer I am seeking is not electroporation-related at all, it's more general, like: which terms defines the method of study that concentrates on modeling (I) how the phenomena occurs and (II) how that phenomena reflects macroscopically on its environment.

Comment: I think you need help from someone who is *au fait* with the technicalities. There wouldn't seem to be much wrong with the English grammar, but I still wouldn't have the faintest idea what it means.

Comment: Well, thank you @WS2 then, seems like I managed to learn English somehow, barely. But I thought I provided enough information to make it clear, but I'm probably wrong... I tried to ask here because it seems like this is like, a broad question. Like, which term defines the method of study that concentrates on modeling (I) how the phenomena occurs and (II) how that phenomena reflects macroscopic on its environment.

Comment: @HericDenis perhaps the [Electrical Engingeering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) would be able to advise you?

Comment: @JulieCarter, probably not... that one seems more focused on technical issues rather then academic. Maybe [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/), but anyways, I think I'll hold on for now, ask my (mentor?) I guess... Thank you.

Comment: Academia doesnt' seem to be the right place either ;)

Comment: @HericDenis you could try rewriting the question title, above, to include reference to electroporation or bioelectronics. This would make it more likely to be noticed by ELU users with knowledge in the field. If your mentor is unable to assist you, related academic institutions, such as the Bioelectrochemical Society, can be useful. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as @pat helped me out on the comments, I will use the terms:

(i) Electroporation mechanisms

(ii) Equivalent conductivity modelling

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion (not enough points for comment)-

Mechanisms.

Interaction Cell and Electric Field Effects (Primary)

Material Flow Effects (Secondary)

From, [Guide to Electroportation and Electrofusion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012168041X)

> A fundamental question about electroportation is whether the membrane
>   pores are shaped mainly by the primary effects of interactions between
>   the applied electric field and the cell membrane, or by a secondary
>   effect of material flow following the initial permeabilization of the
>   cell membrane induced by the electric field.

Comment: It wasn't me that voted down, but this sure isn't what I asked for... What I am seeking is not related to electroporation theory at all! It's a general question (see edited question).

Comment: why not just 1)Mechanisms and 2) Effects?

Comment: Well @pat, the first one ain't bad... I thing Electroporation mechanisms modelling and Equivalent conductivity modelling might be a possible solution.

Comment: I'll hold the question a little further, if I don't get a better solution I'll stick with what I said before.